# Is it harmful for the battery to use a 60 W instead of 45 W charger?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charger

So, my dog bit through my MacBook Air charger and i just ordered one online without really knowing what all the specs meant.

Now my question, does it hurt my battery to use a charger with a higher charging capacity?

Answer (score 4):

Your battery will only take as much as it needs. Thus a larger charger will not harm it.

Comment: A word of caution, though, while it's true that it will only draw the charge it needs, I wouldn't use it for extended periods, as it may lead to battery swelling. This often happens to people charging iPhones with iPad chargers (5W vs 12W) for long periods.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that the charge for the battery requires a specific voltage and a minimum amperage. The wrong voltage will likely destroy things. Ideally, you want the amperage to be no less than what was available previously.

Comment: @SeraH Source? Apple devices will not demand/consume more current than is safe.

Answer (score 0):

In a well-designed device, it should never matter. In constant-current mode, the voltage is varied to keep the amperage going into the cell. If you are charging a 11.1 (3S) battery at 2A, for example, the charging circuitry will not send 11.1v to the battery. Instead, it'll start low, like 10v and slowly adjust until the current desired is met. The difference between the two chargers is the maximum continuous current they can sink before they burn out. In the constant-voltage stage, it really doesn't matter! The voltage is set to a threshold to help the battery complete it's charge cycle. The current is set to freely go up and down as it pleases. However, the more powerful charger still doesn't matter! The current going into the battery will rarely ever reach the current that the lower-end charger will produce.